# XML Schema: all, sequence & groups

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I'm writing an XML schema for the first time and I found some usefull tools to help me writing it.

Now I'm in a strange situation. The schema I wrote is valid for some tools and not for some others.
This schema is a mix of "all", "sequence" and "group". Here is my XML schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <xsd:group name="test">

        <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="e2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:element name="e3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:element name="e4" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:group>

    <xsd:element name="e0">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="e1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xsd:group ref="test"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Is this schema right?
It goes right with [this validator](http://schneegans.de/sv/) and [this one too](http://www.w3.org/2001/03/webdata/xsv) but the XML Tools plugin for Notepad++ says "Unable to parse schema file".

P.S: I wrote this schema because I wanted to have an element "e0" with this the possibility to have a mix of e1, e2, e3 and e4. e2, e3 and e4 should appear 0 or 1 time and e1 could occurs an illimited times.
For example this XML files should pass:

```
<e0>
   <e1/>
   <e1/>
   <e1/>
   <e1/>
   <e1/>
   <e2/>
</e0>

<e0>
   <e2/>
   <e3/>
   <e4/>
</e0>

<e0>
   <e1/>
   <e2/>
   <e3/>
   <e4/>
</e0>
```

Do you know an other way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The schema you have seems to be invalid according to the 1.0 version which states [plainly here (Primer)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#groups) that

*`XML Schema stipulates that an all group must appear as the sole child at the top of a content model.`*

Alternatively, try to read section 3.8.6 of the XML Schema Structures [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#coss-modelGroup). To your list I would add .NET's XSD processor, which in your case will complain as:

*`The group ref to 'all' is not the root particle, or it is being used as an extension.`*

With XSD 1.0 there is no solution that would give you what you want nicely and with a concised syntax unless you build a wrapper for e1 elements (below as e1s).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:group name="test">
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="e1s" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="e1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="e2" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="e3" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="e4" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:group>
    <xsd:element name="e0">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:group ref="test"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

When it comes to e1 elements, they must be wrapped in e1s

```
<e0>
    <e1s>
        <e1/>
        <e1/>
        <e1/>
        <e1/>
        <e1/>
    </e1s>
    <e2/>
</e0>
```

or

```
<e0>
    <e1s>
        <e1/>
    </e1s>
    <e2/>
    <e3/>
    <e4/>
</e0>
```

Then it'll all validate...

Comment: It's quite common to find tools that are over-liberal in what they accept. Xerces and Saxon are both pretty conformant: if those two accept it, then it's probably valid. Which, sadly, doesn't mean it will work everywhere, because some tools are over-restrictive in what they accept...

Comment: OK thanks for your answers! I will try to do it in an other way.

Comment: It's very strange that there isnot solution(at least simple) for such simple task