# The group ref to 'all' is not the root particle, or it is being used as an extension

Tags: xml, xsd

I have created an XSD schema to validate an XML generated by serializing C# classes.

In my first implementation I have used sequences but this caused many problems with the order of the elements within the XML (it causes a validation error, if elements appear in the wrong order). So I thought it would be easy to change every xs:sequence into xs:all, but this does not solve the problem at all, because I want to reference grouped elements...

To illustrate the problem I just created a simple example; please see the XML schema definition below. Please consider that this schema is only to describe my problem so I don't need any hints regards reconsidering the XML structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
       elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="PostalAddresses">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="PostalAddres">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="Street" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="StreetNumber" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="ZipCode" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
            <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:group name="AddressFields">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="BirthDate" type="xs:date" />
    </xs:all>
  </xs:group>

  <xs:element name="Addresses">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:group ref="AddressFields" />
        <xs:element name="PostalAddresses" type="PostalAddresses"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The problem arises within the `Addresses` element where I can´t change the sequence into an all element; I got the following validation error message: The group ref to 'all' is not the root particle, or it is being used as an extension.

Comment: There´s already a solution for that problem at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808244/xml-schema-all-sequence-groups