# XSD: Combine xs:group with xs:all?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am struggling with a xsd where I want to combine a `xs:group` and a `xs:all` entry:

Sample XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <!-- This group will be reused later -->
    <xs:group name="TGroup">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="Mixable1" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Mixable2" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Mixable3" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>

    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:group ref="TGroup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="RootContent1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="RootContent2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                </xs:all>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

(this does not validate as `xs:all` is not allowed in `xs:sequence`)

What I am trying to achieve:
The `root` element should always allow `RootContent1` and `RootContent2` in an arbitrary order (therefore the `xs:all`) and each element should additionally be optional but would still allow all if necessary (in contrast to `xs:choice`)

Furthermore I need a reusable set of nodes (defined by the group `TGroup`) with an arbitrary amount of `MixableX` elements in any order. It is a `xs:group` because the group itself will be reused (in the real xsd) and I want to avoid duplication of declaration.

Some Sample XMLs

```
<root>
    <Mixable1 />
</root>

<root>
    <Mixable2 />
    <RootContent1 />
</root>

<root>
    <Mixable2 />
    <Mixable1 />
    <Mixable2 />
    <RootContent2 />
</root>
```

I have the feeling that what I want to describe is non-deterministic for the parser and therefore not representable with XSD but I might as well just missed something.

Comment: Wouldn't `<xs:choice minOccurs="0">` instead of `<xs:all>` give you what you need?

Comment: @Filburt unfortunately no as this would disallow me to have `RootContent1` and `RootContent2` at the same time but in an arbitrary order. I've updated my post to point that detail out, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check this out : http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_sequence.asp
You will see that you are not allowed to nest xs:all inside of xs:sequence.

Also I tried tricking it by creating a group to contain the  tag, but as it appears, (and also referenced in this post : [XML Schema: all, sequence & groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808244/xml-schema-all-sequence-groups))

> XML Schema stipulates that an all group must appear as the sole child
>   at the top of a content model.

But, if you don't plan on having RootContent1 & 2 simulatenously, then Filburt is right and you could simply go with another choice element:

```
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:group ref="TGroup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
                <xs:element name="RootContent1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="RootContent2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

**Edit: This could be a work around for this specific case**

```
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:group ref="TGroup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:element ref="RootContent1" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element ref="RootContent2" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:element ref="RootContent2" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element ref="RootContent1" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="RootContent2" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="RootContent1" type="xs:string"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the restriction is indeed none up to all and each of them only one. If I could have multiple `RootContent1` and `RootContent2` I could write it like the referenced TGroup but this would alter the xsd semantic a lot

Comment: I am afraid but I think this does not scale well as my current xsd contains about 20 `RootContentX` elements which would require a choice for every permutation of these elements.

Comment: I am afraid you were correct in the first place and there might not be a suitable schema for your needs. I tried tricking it with type extension as well, but no luck. It would appear that there is no solution for this in xml version 1.0 . :(